# Restructure the grouped list

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Pac
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string PacName {get; set;}
    public string PacWorkName {get; set;}
}

public class Bac
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string BacName {get; set;}
    public string PacId {get; set;}
    public string PersonId {get; set;}
}

public class Mac
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public static IList<(string personId, List<Mac>, List<Bac>)> GroupByPersonId(
    IDictionary<Mac, Bac> BacMacPairs,
    IList<Pac> PacsByWorkArea
)
{
    List<(string personId, List<Mac>, List<Bac>)> groupByPersonId = 
    BacMacPairs
    .GroupBy(kv => kv.Value == null ? string.Empty : kv.Value.PersonId)
    .Select(g => (
        g.Key,
        g.Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList(),
        g.Select(kv => kv.Value).Where(s => s!= null).DistinctBy(s => s.Id).ToList()
    ))
    .ToList();

    return groupByPersonId;
}
```

The result from GroupByPersonId is grouped by PersonId in Bac object.

So now I want to group by PacWorkName first and then by PersonId in Bac object. Its okay to have duplicated PersonIds in the list.

Comment: Is `Id` property in `Bac` and `Pac` belongs to `Mac`?

Comment: Nope. Pac, Bac and Mac are all different objects

Comment: There is no `DistinctBy` method in `Linq`, only [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) and you can pass only comparer to this method, not the `Func`  @zzzziiiirrrrkkkkkkkk Are you using your own linq provider?

Comment: Since `PersonId` and `PacWorkName` are members of different collection, you'll need to join them first